# Microsoft SQL search table for entry

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a inventory system for a micro brewery and I have a question about adding customers to a database. I want to add customers only if they don't already have an entry. What command could I use to check for that?
Here's my code so far (ASP.NET)

```
con.ConnectionString = "****"
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer(Name, Address) VALUES('" & Namea & "','" & Addressa & "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer WHERE (Name = '" & Namea & "')"
custID = cmd.ExecuteScalar
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Order_Details_ID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Finished_Inventory_ID=" & OrdersInt & ""
ordrID = cmd.ExecuteScalar
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders(Customer_ID, Order_Details) VALUES(" & Integer.Parse(custID) & "," & Integer.Parse(ordrID) & ")"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Is there a Boolean command that will return `true` if there's already a entry with the specific `Namea`. I don't want multiple entries with the same customer name.

Comment: You need to pick something about the customer that is unique.  The name is not sufficient.  An email address might be ok.

Comment: That's my plan, but how do I search the table to see if that entry already exists. Like if I add mike@example.com one day and then someone else tries to add the same person again. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to prevent duplicate entries.  You can check first:

```
select count(*) records
from etc
```

Then look at the value of records.  If it's 0, do the insert.  Or you can use a subquery.

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where (select count(*) etc ) = 0
```

or like this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select value1, value2, etc
where not exists (select 1 from table etc)
```

In all cases, the etc part is a search for records you don't want to duplicate.